# Saving Keras model and weights

Tags: python, keras, scikit-multilearn

Im using Azure ML Studio to create an automated ML pipeline. I've successfully gotten my model to be trained and tested in Azure, but it fails on `model.to_json()` and `model.save_weights()`.

I believe these functions do not exist on my model as scikit-multilearn is a wrapper around Keras. However, I want to be able to save my model and weight so I can deploy them to a webservice service. The scikit-multilearn model I'm using is Binary Relevance.

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: The class Keras of scikit-multilearn is based on the sklearn.base.BaseEstimator which have the get_params method. You should be able to get your parameters from it and then save it in a file.

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you suggest how I would then load the model back up for production? If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: The get_params method only returns the epochs and batch size params etc, not the Keras model or its weights.